# Counting the number of attachments on a PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, count, itext, attachment

I am trying to count the number of attachments on a PDF to verify our attachment code.  The code I have works most of the time but recently it started failing when the number of attachments went up as well as the size of the attachments.  Example: I have a PDF with 700 attachments which total 1.6 gb. And another with 65 attachments of around 10mb.  The 65 count was done incrementally.  We had built it up file by file.  At 64 files (about 9.8mb) the routine counted fine.  Add file 65 (about .5mb) and the routine failed.

This is on itextpdf-5.5.9.jar under jre1.8.0_162

We are still testing different combinations of file numbers and size to see where it breaks.

```
private static String CountFiles() throws IOException, DocumentException {

    Boolean errorFound = new Boolean(true);
    PdfDictionary root;
    PdfDictionary names;
    PdfDictionary embeddedFiles;
    PdfReader reader = null;
    String theResult = "unknown";

    try {
        if (!theBaseFile.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))
            theResult = "file not PDF";
        else {
            reader = new PdfReader(theBaseFile);
            root = reader.getCatalog();
            names = root.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
            if (names == null)
                theResult = "0";
            else {
                embeddedFiles = names.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
                PdfArray namesArray = embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
                theResult = String.format("%d", namesArray.size() / 2);
            }
            reader.close();
            errorFound = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        theResult = "unknown";
    }
    finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
    if (errorFound)
        sendError(theResult);
    return theResult;
}

private static String AttachFileInDir() throws IOException, DocumentException {

    String theResult = "unknown";
    String outputFile = theBaseFile.replaceFirst("(?i).pdf$", ".attach.pdf");
    int maxFiles = 1000;
    int fileCount = 1;

    PdfReader reader = null;
    PdfStamper stamper = null;

    try {
        if (!theBaseFile.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))
            theResult = "basefile not PDF";
        else if (theFileDir.length() == 0)
            theResult = "no attach directory";
        else if (!Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(theFileDir)))
            theResult = "invalid attach directory";
        else {
            reader = new PdfReader(theBaseFile);
            stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            stamper.getWriter().setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
            Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(theFileDir);
            DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
            for (Path path : stream) {
                stamper.addFileAttachment(null, null, path.toFile().toString(), path.toFile().getName());
                if (++fileCount > maxFiles) {
                    theResult = "maxfiles exceeded";
                    break;
                }
            }
            stream.close();
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
            theResult = "SUCCESS";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        theResult = "unknown";
    }
    finally {
        if (stamper != null)
            stamper.close();
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
    if (theResult != "SUCCESS")
        sendError(theResult);
    return theResult;
}
```

I expect a simple count of attachments back. What seems to be happening is the namesArray is coming back null. The result stays "unknown".  I **suspect** the namesArray is trying to hold all the files and choking on the size.

Note: The files are being attached using the AttachFileInDir procedure.  Dump all the files in a directory and run the AttachFileInDir.  And yes the error trapping in AttachFileInDir needs work.

Any help would be appreciated or another method welcome

Comment: Good question, but would you mention the programming language (it looks like C++) and lead your code with appropriate `#include` and the like? I happen to have some familiarity with Poppler from years ago, so I vaguely recognize your types and calls, but suspect that many readers will not grasp your context. More information, please.

Comment: Wait, this is Java, isn't it? (That is why you should state the language.)

Comment: Yes sorry this is an excerpt from a much bigger java app.  here are the includes:

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;

Comment: theBaseFile is the full path to the PDF.

Comment: Your code is incomplete as it only understands very primitive **EmbeddedFiles** structures. Your recent problem files might have a slightly more complex **EmbeddedFiles** structure. You should improve your code to also understand such more complex structures. [See this answer for background information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23696296/1729265).

Comment: That being said, completely ignoring the exception in a `catch` block usually is inappropriate. You should at least log the message.

Comment: The link you sent me to displays a PDF structure.  How can i introspect my PDF to look for any kids -- i don't know if i have a tool that will do that.  The attachments are added using a very simple iText attach code -- I'll see if i can add it to the post.  Here's some more information.  We've tested incrementally adding files to a single pdf. In the PDF I have 64 files (around 9.8) mb.  Counts fine.  Add another file (about .5mb) and count fails.  That's why I suspect an array issue.  In my situation I wouldn't have gotten a count at 64 if were Kids and since you can't have both.....

Comment: yes the error handler is being improved

Comment: Your description sounds like your PDFs, as soon as the number of attachments reaches a threshold value, contain a non-trivial tree in **EmbeddedFiles**, not a mere tree root. Thus, check whether `embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES)` is 'null'. If it is, retrieve `embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.KIDS)`, recurse into all those objects, and return the sum of the counts returned for them.

Comment: *"How can i introspect my PDF to look for any kids -- i don't know if i have a tool that will do that."* - as you are working with iText, using [iText RUPS](https://itextpdf.com/products/rups-reading-and-updating-pdf-syntax) to inspect PDFs would be natural.

Comment: No RUPS for me.  no way we can buy it.  I'll take a look at the kids when names is null.

Comment: Use Pdfbox debugger App: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/pdfbox/debugger-app/2.0.13/

Comment: after looking at the process we found that after a certain number of attachments Adobe switches from using NAMES to any number of KIDS.  Now we are trying to figure out how to traverse the kids and get a count.

Comment: I've about given up.  For the life of me I cannot seem to get to the multiple kids that are produced.  I can see them in the kidsArray  --  PdfArray kidsArray = embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.KIDS); -- but that's as far as I can get.

Comment: @wrkoch I can confirm that it is impossible to buy RUPS because RUPS only exists as an open source, AGPLv3 application - which means that you don't have to pay for it.

Comment: iTextRUPS is a pay for tool.  https://itextpdf.com/en/products/rups-reading-and-updating-pdf-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it.  Turns out each KID is a dictionary of NAMES….

Each NAMES hold 64 file references.  At 65 files and up it made a KIDS dictionary array of names.  So 279 files = ( 8*64 +46 )/2  (9 total KIDS array elements).

One thing that I had to compensate for.  If one deletes all the attachments off a pdf it leaves artifacts behind as opposed to a PDF that never had an attachment

```
private static String CountFiles() throws IOException, DocumentException {

    Boolean errorFound = new Boolean(true);
    int totalFiles = 0;
    PdfArray filesArray;
    PdfDictionary root;
    PdfDictionary names;
    PdfDictionary embeddedFiles;
    PdfReader reader = null;
    String theResult = "unknown";

    try {
        if (!theBaseFile.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))
            theResult = "file not PDF";
        else {
            reader = new PdfReader(theBaseFile);
            root = reader.getCatalog();
            names = root.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
            if (names == null){
                theResult = "0";
                errorFound = false;
            }
            else {
                embeddedFiles = names.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
                filesArray = embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
                if (filesArray != null)
                    totalFiles = filesArray.size();
                else {
                    filesArray = embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.KIDS);
                    if (filesArray != null){
                        for (int i = 0; i < filesArray.size(); i++)
                            totalFiles += filesArray.getAsDict(i).getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES).size();                         
                    }
                }
                theResult = String.format("%d", totalFiles / 2);
                reader.close();
                errorFound = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        theResult = "unknown" + e.getMessage();
    }
    finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
    if (errorFound)
        sendError(theResult);
    return theResult;
}
```

Comment: Please read again the quote from the specification in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23696296/1729265). Your original code could handle only trees with only a root. Your code here can handle only trees with either only a root or a root and one level beyond. But the specification allows trees with an arbitrary depth.

Comment: So are you saying there can be kids in kids?  What causes that to happen?  Can you offer a code improvement ?

Comment: *"So are you saying there can be kids in kids?"* - yes, cf. the answer I referred to. *"What causes that to happen?"* - it is completely up to the pdf generating program/library how it constructs this ml name tree.